# Wix registry editing not displayed in the msi log

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer

I've been working on a WIX .net project that needs to update a Microsoft registry entry to work correctly.  While testing the logic, I found it difficult to debug the WIX components that updates the registry via the [MSiexec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command line /log options. To verify the correct behaviour, I had to check the registry value manually. How do I force the WIX project to log the registry search and update logic from the following fragment in the MSI log output?

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="Office2013RegistySearch"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel"
                     Value="TypeGuessRows"
                     Variable="Office2013GuessRowsx86Exist"
                     Win64="no"
                     Result="exists" />   

<Component Id="Office2013GuessRowsx86RegComponent" Guid="CFE579F9-292A-4777-A671-B5E8E330B1A0" Win64="no">
    <Condition>Office2013GuessRowsx86Exists</Condition>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                 Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="no">
      <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="TypeGuessRows" Value="0"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use full log

> msiexec /i "dotnetproject.msi" /L*v "log.log"

or add `<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="voicewarmup"/>` (for full log too)